# Simple slider values in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am using Jquery simple slider. The total simple sliders is not fixed and it will change dynamically. For example, I will get the input from the user and based on the input I will have those many simple sliders. So far everything is fine. Now, I need to pass the values the user selected for all the simple sliders to the next page. This is the code I have so far.

```
<form action = "update.php" method="post"><input type="submit" name="submit"value="SUBMIT"></form>
$("submit").change(function () {
    var value = this.value.substring(1);
    console.log(value);
    $("#slider").slider("value", parseInt(value));
});
</script>
```

However, I am not able to see the values in the update.php file. I also tried using $_POST and $_GET. I was not able to retrieve the simple slider values.

Comment: add a hidden form element that you populate with the js

Comment: Should the form be included inside the jquery?

Comment: all the js should be in the page head